# How to describe formly custom field options type to pass angular strictTemplates check?

Tags: angular, typescript, ngx-formly

I have angular app with strictTemplates option turned on. I can't get how to describe options type to pass strcitTemplates check.

Tempalte which rise error:

```html
<p-multiSelect [options]="$any(props.options)"
               [formControl]="formControl"
               [formlyAttributes]="field" />
```

Component:

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FieldType, FieldTypeConfig } from '@ngx-formly/core'

@Component({
    selector: 'form-multiselect',
    templateUrl: 'multiselect.component.html',
})
export class MultiselectComponent extends FieldType<FieldTypeConfig> {

}
```

If you remove `$any` type casting in template. You get:

```
TS2322: Type 'any[] | Observable<any[]> | undefined' is not assignable to type 'any[] | undefined'.
```

I can't understand how to extend `FieldType<FieldTypeConfig>` type to let it know that I have array always.

Comment: what's the provider for `<p-multiSelect>` tag?

Comment: sorry, it's Primeng multiselect - https://primeng.org/multiselect